# How to pass data from routes group to its controllers?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-controller

I have a routes group in Laravel that gets a parameter like below:

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => '{ProjectCode}'], function () {
    Route::get('/categories', 'CategoriesController@Categories');
    Route::get('/add-category', 'CategoriesController@AddCategory');
});
```

The `ProjectCode` is an id, that is used to get some data from the database
I want to pass the retrieved data to controllers that they are in sub of the route group and avoid getting data in every function in controller

Comment: create a middleware that will be easier.

Comment: Have you tried [Implicit](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#implicit-binding) or [Explicit](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/routing#explicit-binding) route binding? This is typically how models are pulled before a controller.

Comment: @LLai thanks , I will try it, this is ok to use it in multiple groups as a sub ? I mean declare it in a group and use it in other sub groups

Comment: @shyammakwana.me thanks , but how can I get the returned data and pass them into all controllers in group route?

Comment: This I'm not 100% sure on. I've typically used route binding directly in routes and not in groups, but I'm guessing it will work

Comment: Do you have a model named `App\ProjectCode`? because afaik, your code should work as it is

Comment: no, I haven't created that , but if I create it how can I use it to pass the got data to controllers?

Comment: @Meraj in middleware write your value to `$request` like `$request->data = $dataFromModel`. then it will be available in following routes or nearly anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use "Implicit/Explicit Route Model Binding", assuming you have `Project` model, you can have this controller method (use camelCase for parameters and controllers' methods name not PascalCase):

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => '{projectCode}'], function () {
    Route::get('/categories', 'CategoriesController@pategories');
    Route::get('/add-category', 'CategoriesController@addCategory');
});  

class CategoriesController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @param  Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function categories(\App\Project $projectCode)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

You may wish to use your own resolution binding, override the `resolveRouteBinding` on your model:

```php
/**
* Retrieve the model for a bound value.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @param  string|null  $field
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
 */
public function resolveRouteBinding($value, $field = null)
{
    return $this->where($field ?? $this->getRouteKeyName(), $value)->first();
}
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/routing#implicit-binding) for more info.